# Chat app using Thread and sockets. How to send a message when a user exits?

Tags: python-3.x, sockets, user-interface

I created a chat app ,server-clients based, using Threads, sockets and GUI.
I want to make it so once a user exits his/her GUI screen it sends a message to 
the rest of the users the person has left. How can I do so? The send() command doesn't seem to work after the user exits the GUI screen.

Note: I'm using python 3.6.5

Comment: You don't mention what GUI framework you are using.  If you are not using one in  particular, try PySimpleGUI.  You'll find a chat window demo application posted.  You'll just need to wire up your sockets stuff and you'll be done.

Comment: Hmmm... then again maybe not with your multithreaded stuff